# Youtube API 3.0: Get specific playlist from channel

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

What is working: getting the latest videos from the uploads playlist in a channel.

What is not working: getting the latest videos from a specific playlist in a channel. With "specific" i mean playlist like this one here:
http://www.youtube.com/user/fckoeln/videos?tag_id=UCQZhvmm636X6I5rrnLFBp1w.3.netcologne-fc-tv-star-talk&flow=grid&view=46

For example the playlistId for the uploads playlist is "UUQZhvmm636X6I5rrnLFBp1w" and that works.
Now i assumed the playlistId for this specific playlist would be "UCQZhvmm636X6I5rrnLFBp1w.3.netcologne-fc-tv-star-talk", but it's not working.

I'm also not able to get the playlistId for this by querying for the contentDetails of the channel, this playlist doesn't exist there.

Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I am banging my head against the wall, because this is the first time I've seen a playlist in the above format (with tag_id= in the URL), usually a playlist would have the url of something like this: youtube.com/playlist?list=UCQZhvmm636X6I5rrnLFBp1w, however your above example has too many chars for a playlist id (which is 16 chars strictly).

I wasn't able to find anything in the Youtube API documentation in regards to that tag_id query.

Obviously, you'd want to return results similar to a list like this: gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/BK6tyexCQakO9SGMFiv_GJYvc61eQ7yX?v=2&max-results=50&orderby=position
like a normal playlist, but I saw nothing in the YouTube API to find the ID of this type of playlist (which, again first time I new this type existed).

Sorry I couldn't be more helpful and hopefully you can find a solution. I tried lookign at the Youtube API reference to see if there was a way you could query the results from your request from the User Account (something like gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/users/fckoeln/uploads?alt=rss&v=2&orderby=published&client=ytapi-youtube-profile&q=%22netcologne-fc-tv-star-talk%22 but not as idiotic) but nothing was readily apparent from the documentation

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference

Comment: Thanks for your answers even it contains no solution to the problem. Yes, i also see this "type of playlist" for the first time. I hope it will be possible to query this one ... the question is: what playlist id to query? maybe someone from google/youtube can give an answer to this question... (on https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/youtube-api-gdata is stackoverflow metioned as their "official forum")

Comment: Fount out that there is some kind of "list-id" here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j89euWlo4_E&playnext=1&list=TL7dhVOifyh-c Bute the "TL7dhVOifyh-c" isn't 16 characters and will not work with the playlistItems query.